# What's the proper way of showing multiple type of rows on a react-native list view?

Tags: android, ios, listview, react-native, react-native-listview

So what we want is something like:

[multiple-row-type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBOO5.jpg)

In iOS we could use multiple cellIdentifier for each cell type to create performant listview.

What I have now is something like

```
render() {
  const dataBlob = [
    { type: "address", data: { address, gotoEditAddress } },

    { type: "deliveryTime", data: {...} },

    { type: "cartSummary", data: {...} },

    ...[items.map(item => {{ type: "item", data: {...} }})],

    { type: "paymentInformation", data: {...} },
    { type: "paymentBreakdown", data: {...} },
    { type: "promoCode", data: {...} },
  ];

  this._dataSource = this._dataSource.cloneWithRows(dataBlob);

  return (
    <ListView ref="ScrollView"
        renderRow={this._renderRow}
        dataSource={this._dataSource} />
  );
)
```

and on the renderRow method

```
_renderRow = (rowData) => {
  const { type, data } = rowData;
  if (type === "address") return <AddressRow {...data} />;
  if (type === "deliveryTime") return <DeliveryTimeRow {...data} />;
  if (type === "menuItem") return <MenuItemRow {...data} />;
  if (type === "cartSummary") return <CartSummaryRow {...data} />;

  if (type === "promoCode") return <PromoCodeRow {...data} />;
  if (type === "paymentInformation") return <PaymentRow {...data} />;
  if (type === "paymentBreakdown") return <PaymentBreakdownRow {...data} />;

  return null;
};
```

The problem with the above code is that it's making the dataSource.rowHasChanged method to be really complicated to implement correctly.

and for some reason when I removed a row, in RN0.31 you will have some ui-defects as such:

[ui-defects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxWbP.jpg)

Comment: In case anyone wondering, in the end we're just using scrollview since the maximum number of row is quite limited (< 20)

Answer (score 3):

I did not fully understand  the question. But I'm going to attempt this one.

Instead of rendering multiple types of rows, you can render the same Row component but have different contents inside. It's going to be hard to manage and render different types of rows.

You can pass the type of row you want to render as a prop to a common `Row` component and have it rendered.

So your second code snippet would look like this -

```
_renderRow = (rowData) => {
  const { type, data } = rowData;
  switch(type) {
    case 'address':
      return <Row component={AddressRow} data={...data} />;
    case 'deliveryTime':
      return <Row component={DeliveryTime} data={...data} />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

`Row` would simply construct the supplied row and return the component. So on top level you'll have only `Row`s. `Row` will contain the particular component you want to render.

`render` of `Row`:

```
render() {
  const Component = this.props.component
  return <Component {...this.props.data} />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but this will still requires us to make really awkward rowHasChanged function (I guess unless we use immutable)